# My Java SQS Consumer is only consuming when i call it not by itself

Tags: java, amazon-sqs

I am using the aws sdk for java specifically the sdk version 2.21.0, however my situation is the following, I am developing a consumer for a queue in AWS SQS, the consumer works fine, it brings the messages and everything, but only when I call the method, that is, not when a message is published but only when I call it is that it processes the messages, I do not want this behavior because I want to process the messages by itself once they are published, I want to know what happens

the AmazonSQSAsync bean:

```
@Bean
    @Primary
    public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync() {
        BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(Enviromentals.KeyProvider.ACCESS_KEY,
                Enviromentals.KeyProvider.SECRET_KEY);
        return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .build();
    }
```

the consumer method:

```
public List<Message> consumeMessageFromSQS() {
    AmazonSQS sqsClient = sqsClientBuilder();
    System.out.println("al escuchar entro a este metodo");
    //ReceiveMessageRequest request = new ReceiveMessageRequest(Enviromentals.AwsEnvs.DEPOSIT_QUEUE_ENDPOINT_URI).withMaxNumberOfMessages(10);

    List<Message> sqsMessages = sqsClient.receiveMessage(Enviromentals.AwsEnvs.DEPOSIT_QUEUE_ENDPOINT_URI).getMessages();
    for (Message message : sqsMessages) {
        //run process for message
        System.out.println(message.getBody());
        
        //dequeue message after using it
        //also perfect step so check if message was successfully processed
        dequeuMessageFromSQS(message);
    }
    return sqsMessages;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what app framework you're using, but basically you need to spin up a thread that calls `consumeMessageFromSQS()` repeatedly (or continually tasks that do that, one at a time, and put those on an ExecutorService). Basically, something needs to make sure that you're calling `consumeMessageFromSQS()` as soon as you're ready for a batch. SQS can't call that method on behalf of your code.

Comment: Oh, to add: depending on your use case, you might consider putting the code into a Lambda. Then you _can_ set up a trigger such that the SQS will automatically invoke your code. This will be a good option if the queue is usually empty; otherwise, you'll be running the Lambda "hot" (ie, running very frequently), and that's significantly more expensive than more raw compute like ECS/EKS.

Answer (score 0):

SQS can't push messages to your endpoint or invoke anything. It's your responsibility to pull messages periodically. So you need to wrap your `consumeMessageFromSQS` method into a scheduled worker that is invoked every N seconds and polls for new messages.